# Use `callNextMethod()` with dotsMethods

Tags: r, oop, generics, r-s4

I would like to define some S4 generics dispatching on the `...` argument such that the more specialized methods call the inherited method through `callNextMethod()`. However, as illustrated by the MWE, this fails with the following error.

```
# sample function which returns the number of its arguments
f <- function(...) length(list(...))

setGeneric("f")
## [1] "f"

setMethod("f", "character", function(...){ print("character"); callNextMethod() })
## [1] "f"

f(1, 2, 3)
## [1] 3

f("a", "b", "c")
## [1] "character"
## Error in callNextMethod(): a call to callNextMethod() appears in a call to '.Method', but the call does not seem to come from either a generic function or another 'callNextMethod'
```

This behavior doesn't seem right to me, but maybe I'm missing something here. I would expect the failing `callNextMethod()` to dispatch to the inherited default method `function(...) length(list(...))` effectively returning:

```
## [1] "character"
## [1] 3
```

Any thoughts on this?

## Update

Additionally, I've found the following difference in behavior between S4 methods dispatching on formal arguments and ones dispatching on `...`. Consider the following example where switching the signature from `x` to `...` changes the way objects are resolved.

```
f = function(x, ..., a = b) {
  b = "missing 'a'"
  cat(a)
}

f()
## missing 'a'

f(a = 1)
## 1

setGeneric("f", signature = "x")

f()
## missing 'a'

setGeneric("f", signature = "...")

f()
## Error in cat(a) : object 'b' not found
```

According to `?dotsMethods` the dispatch on `...` is implemented differently, but as suggested in the last sentence, this shouldn't cause any differences in behavior compared to regular generics. However, the above findings seem to prove the opposite.

> Methods dispatching on “...” were introduced in version 2.8.0 of R. The initial implementation of the corresponding selection and dispatch is in an R function, for flexibility while the new mechanism is being studied. In this implementation, a local version of setGeneric is inserted in the generic function's environment. The local version selects a method according to the criteria above and calls that method, from the environment of the generic function. This is slightly different from the action taken by the C implementation when “...” is not involved. Aside from the extra computing time required, the method is evaluated in a true function call, as opposed to the special context constructed by the C version (which cannot be exactly replicated in R code.) **However, situations in which different computational results would be obtained have not been encountered so far, and seem very unlikely.**

Comment: These issues will be resolved in the first patch release of R 3.4.